# PHP inserting weird space when including files sequentially

Tags: php, css, html, templates

I'm writing an application that includes template.phtml files as defined by a config file, the function looks something akin to this:

View.php, `View->render()` :

```
public function render(){
    $this->addTemplates();
    if($this->vars !== null) extract($this->vars);

    if($this->options['noTemplates'] === False){
        foreach($this->templates['before'] as $fn){
            if(file_exists($fn)){
                include($fn); // <-- This is where templates are included
            } else {
                //error handling
            }
        }
    }

    /* Happens 2 more times in an identical fashion
     * for view files and 'after' templates 
     */

}
```

and I've tested it with as simple files as this:

head.phtml:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

</head>
<body>
```

header.phtml:

```
<div class="header">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="menu nav">
            <span class="menu-pre"></span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href=""><span>Item 1</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span>Dropdown</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href=""><span>Item 2</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href=""><span>Item 3</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href=""><span>Item 4</span></a></li>
            </ul>
            <span class="menu-post"></span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
```

and then a standard footer, etc...

the PROBLEM comes from a random space being inserted somewhere, causing a gap to appear at the top of the page:

[image: The gap]

With the following showing in element inspector:

[image: The gap in element inspector]

I've tried this in multiple browser with no happiness, I have a CSS reset, and the inspector shows no extraneous padding or margins, just...a gap for some reason.

The weird thing is, if I include the contents of **header.phtml** inside **head.phtml**, i.e. I manually put the contents of header.phtml inside the head.phtml file, then the gap **doesn't appear** in the output.

In *any* cases, the output from view source looks **exactly** the same, byte for byte.

Things I have tried:

- All manner of CSS resets.
- including the `<body>` tag inside header.phtml (doesn't seem to fix anything...??)
- The code passes html5 validation
- Wrapping the includes in `ob_start()` and `ob_end_flush()`
- Gone through every files included (`using get_included_files()` in PHP) to check for anything being outputted - all files are properly unclosed (no closing PHP tags) with no rogue spaces before the opening `<?php` file.

And to be honest...I can't think what could possibly be causing this issue...is it the PHP output buffering or something?

Answer (score 1):

Check every .php file. There cannot be any single line before `<?php`. Also, if your php code is last thing in the file, then remove `?>`. Also, be sure that there is no empty line between `?> .. <?php` tags and no empty lines in `.html` files.

Annoying issue, I had it few years ago. Now I never use html in php files, always type `<?php` in the first line and never type `?>` at the end of `.php` file and problem is gone :)

Comment: Oh yeah I forgot to mention, I used PHP's get_included_files and checked EVERY (circa 90 files) file - none of them have any output (all of them are unclosed). The real mystery is that including the output of the second included file inside the first solves the issue, but not the other way around (first in second).